# Hometown is not offered in Facebook, only nearby locations

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

I want to add my hometown on my Facebook Timeline but there isn't a matching option. It's an actual suburb (Dulwich Hill, New South Wales) but it doesn't have the option for me to add it to my info, so I have to choose the nearest suburb to me.

How can I add a location or suburb to my hometown field in Facebook when it's not one of the suggested locations?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new place and checkin to it https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=175921872462772 then you should be able to add the new place as a hometown.